# Can I use Conditional Formatting in MS Project to change text color based on Task Name Text?

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting, ms-project

In MS Projects, I need to utilize VBA to conditionally format all rows with "payment" somewhere in the Task Name to have bold, red text.

Comment: Your question received an immediate down-vote because it does not meet the guidelines of StackOverflow. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to improve it. To get started on writing the code, search stackoverflow for [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dcolor). Read other [articles about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on extended comments on prior answer, here is another version of a macro to format the entire row of tasks that contain 'payment' or 'go-live' in the task name.

```
Sub FormatSpecificTasks()

    OutlineShowAllTasks
    FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True _
        , OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Name", Test:="contains" _
        , Value:="payment", ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="" _
        , NewFieldName:="Name", Test:="contains", Value:="go-live" _
        , Operation:="Or", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
    FilterApply Name:="temp"
    SelectAll
    Font32Ex Bold:=True, Color:=255, CellColor:=RGB(255, 229, 99) 
    FilterApply Name:="all tasks"
    OrganizerDeleteItem Type:=pjFilters, FileName:=ActiveProject.Name, Name:="temp"
            
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! Appreciate the support!

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want.

```
Option Compare Text
Sub BoldRed()
OutlineShowAllTasks
FilterEdit Name:="temp", taskfilter:=True, create:=True, overwriteexisting:=True, FieldName:="Name", test:="contains", _
    Value:="payment", ShowInMenu:=False, showsummarytasks:=True
FilterApply Name:="Temp"
SelectTaskColumn Column:="name"
Font32Ex Bold:=True
Font32Ex Color:=255
FilterApply Name:="all tasks"
OrganizerDeleteItem Type:=pjFilters, FileName:=ActiveProject.Name, Name:="temp"
            
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: Unless you want the payment tasks' parent tasks (eg summary tasks) to also be formatted in red, use `ShowSummaryTasks:=False`.

Comment: This may be trickier - can I use the code above in an If-Then iteration? I want to change the color if "payment" is present or if "Go-Live" is present or if "Full go-live" is present change cell color, too?

Comment: @RachelHettinger, I am unable to edit my comment to tag you in my If-Then comment; would you please review above and advise?

Comment: @cnpulse To add additional criteria to the filter add this line after the first FilterEdit: `FilterEdit Name:="temp", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Name", test:="contains", Value:="go-live", Operation:="Or", ShowSummaryTasks:=False`.

Comment: @RachelHettinger - Thank you! Two additional questions - 1) I cannot get the text for the entire row to change color using the SelectRow command before the Font32Ex code; and 2) how do I change the cell background color for rows with specific text to Hex color #FEE599?

Comment: @cnpulse Use `SelectAll` instead of SelectRow to format all text, and use `Font32Ex Color:=255, CellColor:=#FEE599`.

Comment: @RachelHettinger, I keep receiving a compile error at the # and a different error if I switch it over to RGB values. So I feel like my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: @cnpulse yes, use the RGB function instead

Comment: @RachelHettinger I am still unable to affect the whole row or change the cell color programmatically. When I am allowed to post again, I will post the entirety of my code for assistance.